# Demonstrating quadratic residues through three different lemmas

Tags: modular-arithmetic, quadratic-residues

I'm trying to prove that 7 is quadratic residue module 29 using Euler's and Gauss's lemmas. The demonstration with Euler's was immediate (since $7^{14} \equiv 1 \pmod {29} $), But I don't know how to start building the polynomial used in the gauss lemma.
Is there a second form of the gauss lemma?

Comment: Did you mean $29$ when you typed $30$?

Comment: Can you state which Gauss lemma you're using? The one related to quadratic reciprocity (which makes sense given your context) is almost immediate. If you're stuck, please show your work.